# Getting Error 'Cannot read property "length" from undefined' in script mediator esb wso2

Tags: javascript, arrays, wso2, esb, mediator

When I am writing code for transformation of json array to xml array in esb wso2 using script mediator, I am getting error "Cannot read property "length" from undefined". Please help.
My script mediator code is

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
                  payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
    results = payload.results;
    var response = <locations/>;
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        var elem = results[i];
        response.locations += <jacdevice>
            <JACDeviceId>{elem.Id}</JACDeviceId>
            <Make>{elem.ManufacturerName}</Make>
            <Model>{elem.ModelName}</Model>
        </jacdevice>
    }
    mc.setPayloadXML(response);
                ]]></script>
```

Detailed error is

```
ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (<Unknown Source>#4) in <Unknown Source> at line number 4
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:233)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:256)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:766)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what is your json look like? Put a log full just before script mediator and see it's the expected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `results = payload.Results;` instead of `results = payload.results;`

If that doesn't work, try this.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(payload)
results = jsonData.Results;
```

Comment: Yes by trying  results = payload.Results; It worked...thanks for the answer Bhathiya

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error pretty much tells you what's wrong.  At this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
```

The variable `results` is undefined.

That strongly suggests either your call to `mc.getPayloadJSON()` failed or it returned results in a format you didn't expect.  Try debugging from there.

Comment: I have verified the json payload, it is valid. Now how can i verify what mc.getPayloadJSON() is returning?

Comment: Set a breakpoint immediately after the method call and inspect the contents of the variable `results`.

Comment: This is not .java code. It is .xml file, So I am not able to debug it.